# Proxy PAC not working

Tags: windows, proxy, pac

I have an insanely simple proxy pac file i'm trying to get working.. it looks like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

    return "PROXY 66.232.xxx.xxx:808";
}
```

FYI, I xxx'd out the IP to hide it for this question :)

I have validated that the proxy works when manually added to Firefox (not in the Automatic Proxy configuration URL section).

However, when I reference the URL http://integrations.mydomain.com/proxyconfig.pac in Firefox under the "Automatic Proxy configuration URL" it does not work.

I've also tried the URL in IE.

OS is Windows XP Pro SP3 - Firefox version is 35.0.1

I have confirmed the pac URL works, when visiting the pac URL directly it prompts me to download the pac file, and the file downloaded contains the js function.

Would love to get this working, have been googling for the past few days with zero success :(

Thanks in advance